# Why wont my bones respond to the shortcut keys?

Tags: rigging, edit-mode

So, I'm using rigify to rig my character, but the problem is, none of the bones will rotate or scale using the S and R shortcut keys. I can move most of them using the arrows and g shortcut, but unless I specifically go to the transform tab (shown below) and use one of the x, y and z values to rotate or scale it, it won't repond.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot, for better understanding ?

Comment: there you go...

Comment: Thanks, sorry, but its not showing here clear, can you please add the toolbar, full view of blender please

Comment: i updated my question